# JHipster - Cannot connect to dev postgres DB with liquibase on gradle build

Tags: gradle, jhipster, liquibase

Im trying to connect to my dev database that is PostgreSQL.

I have edited `src/main/resource/config/application-dev.yml` to match credentials that make so it can log in to the database and have rights to edit/create tables and so on.

I also tried running the task/command `./gradlew liquibaseUpdate` but it fails because it's using a wrong username.

But it does not do it, What config file am I missing in the liquibase for it to run correctly and for it to make tables so I can log in into the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gradle liquibase does not read `application-dev.yml`, you must configure it directly in `build.gradle` file.